# Line graph with achartengine android

Tags: android, achartengine

Iam having problems with displaying the chart values for a line graph in achartengine. I fetch the data for the lines in an array from the database. The line is plotted perfectly with each point showing. I use `renderer.isDisplayChartValues();` to display values above the points. But the problem is only few values are displayed above the point whereas some have just the points with no values displayed.

heres my code:

```
rendererA = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        rendererA.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        rendererA.isDisplayChartValues();
        rendererA.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFDC143C"));
        rendererA.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
        rendererA.setFillPoints(true);
        rRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(rendererA);

        rendererB= new XYSeriesRenderer();
        rendererB.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        rendererB.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);

        rendererB.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FF6B8E23"));
        rendererB.setFillPoints(true);
        rRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(rendererB);
```

Here is a screenshot.
Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the minimum distance (in pixels) between chart values in order to get several of them displayed. For instance:

```
renderer.setDisplayChartValuesDistance(50);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. It worked. Though I had to modify the distance to 10.